# Does Test-Path accept Relative Paths?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Relative paths seem to work when using `Test-Path` cmdlet, but I can't find any official documentation supporting this.

If they are supported:

- do they work in Powershell 2.0?
- which *path* are they *relative* to?

  - Script path? Execution path? somewhere else?
- how does one change the root relative path? (e.g. script path to something else)

My limited testing suggests that it's relative to the script path (the folder in which the script resides). Is this always the case? If so, then I could reliably use `Join-Path` to alter that path.

Comment: in PoSh, a relative path is relative to the location that PoSh thinks is the current location. that can be where the script started, where the OS current location was when the script started, OR where the script has set the current location. ///// _as with all scripting or programming languages ... DO NOT use relative paths if you can avoid it.__ **_the ambiguity is dangerous._**

Comment: I would recommend checking out the following document on PATH syntax. The documents don't seem to go back to 2.0, at least that I could quickly find. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_path_syntax?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: As for 'current working location', check out the document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_locations?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Safest route is to use automatic variables such as `$PSScriptRoot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) accepts relative paths.

As is *typical*, a relative path is interpreted as **relative to the session's *current [location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Locations)***, as reflected in the [automatic `$PWD` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd) and in the output from [`Get-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location).

The current location can also be represented as `.`

Note that while locations are typically file-system *directories*, PowerShell's [provider model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) allows for other data stores to be presented in a file-system-like manner as well, such as the registry on Windows, for instance (drives `HKCU:` and `HKLM:`)

Therefore, the following commands are equivalent:

```sh
# Test if an item named 'foo' exists in the current location.
# If the current location is a *file-system* location, this
# could be either a file or a directory. 
# Add:
#  -PathType Container to test only for a directory (container item)
#  -PathType Leaf to test only for a file (leaf item)
Test-Path foo
Test-Path .\foo
Test-Path (Join-Path $PWD foo)
```

As [Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) notes, in *scripts* it is better to use *full* paths instead - unless you carefully control the current location beforehand, but note that changing the current location (with [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) or [`Push-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location)) changes it *session-wide*, so it's best to *restore* the previous location before exiting your script, which you can do via paired `Push-Location` / [`Pop-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/pop-location) calls.

---

If, by contrast, you need to **test a path relative to your *script*'s location**, use the [automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot), as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) suggests:

```sh
# Test if a file or directory named 'foo' exists in the directory
# in which the enclosing script is located.
Test-Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot foo)
```